# Can't write string of 1 and 0 to binary file, C++

Tags: c++, binary

I have the function that receives a pointer to a string with a name of file to open and to code with 1 and 0; 
**codedLine** contains something like *010100110101110101010011*
After writing to binary file I have exactly the same...Would would you recommend? Thank you.

```
    void codeFile(char *s)
{
    char *buf = new char[maxStringLength];
    std::ifstream fileToCode(s);
    std::ofstream codedFile("codedFile.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if (!fileToCode.is_open())
        return;
    while (fileToCode.getline(buf, maxStringLength))
    {
        std::string codedLine = codeLine(buf);
        codedFile.write(codedLine.c_str(), codedLine.size());
    }
    codedFile.close();
    fileToCode.close();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: the thing is I can't write the string of 101010101 for example, as binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After writing to binary file I have exactly the same...

I suppose you want to convert the `std::string` input to its binary equivalent.

You can use the [`std::bitset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) class to convert strings to binary values and vice versa. Writing the string directly to the file results in binary representations of the character values `'0'` and `'1'`.

An example how to use it:

```
std::string zeroes_and_ones = "1011100001111010010";
// Define a bitset that can hold sizeof(unsigned long) bits
std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned long) * 8> bits(zeroes_and_ones);

unsigned long binary_value = bits.to_ulong();

// write the binary value to file
codedFile.write((const char*)&binary_value, sizeof(unsigned long));
```

**NOTE**
The above sample works with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standards. For earlier version the `std::bitset` can't be initialized directly from the string. But it can be filled using the `operator>>()`  and `std::istringstream` for example.

Comment: @Eugene Sorry, there was another little flaw in my example. See the definition of the `std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned long) * 8>`!