# How to write a byte represented as a bitstring to a file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

For example, I have a

```
string str = "10010010";
```

How do I write this as a single byte to a file?

Not to write string `"10010010"`, but to have `0b10010010` when I look at a  bits dump of the file.

Comment: You convert it to a number first.

Comment: `std::bitset` will do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't write string of 1 and 0 to binary file, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591429/cant-write-string-of-1-and-0-to-binary-file-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
std::string str = "10010010";
uint8_t byte = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::bitset<8>(str).to_ulong() & 0xFFul);
file.write(&byte,1);
```

References:

- [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)
- [`std::ostream::write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)

Comment: Upvote but shouldn't the cast technically be `static_cast<uint8_t>(std::bitset<8>(bits).to_ulong() & 0xFFul);` in C++?

Comment: @JustinRandall Thanks for cast nitpicking, Now we made it open for short typing fetishists' nitpicks.

Comment: that's what we're all here for isn't it? ;-)